# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large; uploading a file from angular front end to express server

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am facing  the error: "PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large" uploading a file;
this is the code in the frontend:

```
const url = "https://dev.thinkingadditive.com/v0/assets"
const options = {
headers:new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  "x-jwt": `Bearer ${token}`,
  Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
}),
observe:'body' as const,
withCredentials:true
}
return this.http.post(url,asset,options)
```

this the code in the backend:

```
var app = express();
app.disable("x-powered-by");
app.use(
cors({
origin:["url1","url2",'null'                                        ],
credentials: true,
exposedHeaders: "Location"
})
app.use(express.json({limit:'50mb'}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:'50mb',
extended:true,
parameterLimit: 50000
}))
```

the file I want to upload is only 489,9 kb, trhen I do not expect this error